# Count if two criteria match while ignoring duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple Sheet with 2 cells that I need to countif 2 conditions match and treat 
duplicates as 1.

```
Column A    Column B
Male        closed
Female      invalid #
Male        exception
Male        closed
Male        closed
Female      new
```

I would like a formula that counts Male closed and return 1 result (ignoring duplicates)

Comment: @SivaCharan It may help to look at the preview when you edit. There was an extra tab character that was throwing things off.

Comment: Do you want the number of males, or something else about them?

Comment: thanks @soandos for the update. I will take care next time, while updating...

Comment: @Tom: Are you looking for eliminating duplicates and displaying unique results?

Comment: 2 conditions need to be meet like male + closed (2 columns) however only whant to count that conditions 1 time rather then 1000 times that appears

Comment: basic would be if male 1 male 1 male 2 male 3 male 1 in columns looking to count "male 1 search should only return 1 count"

Comment: @Tom: here am bit confused. Can you tell whats your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to count the **different** order numbers (in column B) that are complete (column A) try this

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$100="Complete",MATCH(B$2:B$100,B$2:B$100,0)),ROW(B$2:B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

To add another condition, e.g. assuming status in A and Store Id in B as before but with Sales Reps in column C you can use this version

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$100="Complete",IF(C$2:C$100="Rep1",MATCH(B$2:B$100,B$2:B$100,0))),ROW(B$2:B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))`

of course you can use cells to store the criteria if you wish

Comment: thank you this works great! can I add a 3rd value to key off like sales code+sales rep+status (counting code only once like before ignoring dupes) so keying off 3 column fields Store ID, Sales rep, Status, ignoring dupes in store ID

Comment: I edited my answer to include another condition...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for this output:-

1. Click `Data`
2. Click `Advanced` from `Sort & Filter`
3. Do as per my screenshot
4. Result will be at **F and G Columns**

[image]

### Update:

Count the unique cells,

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(B:B,B:B)>0,1))
```

**Result:**

6

**Example Data:**

```
A           B
thank you   941000106879
complete    941000106879
complete    941000106879
complete    941000107445
complete    941000107445
complete    941000107445
complete    941000107445
complete    941000107446
complete    941000107447
complete    941000107451
complete    941000107451
complete    941000107451
complete    941000107451
complete    941000107451
complete    941000107456
complete    941000107456
complete    941000107456
complete    941000107456
```

Comment: ok its a little more complicated I guess

Comment: @Tom: so you need same output with formulas.. or something else

Comment: this set of results should return 6 count because some of the results repeat                                      thank you      941000106879 complete
941000106879 complete
941000106879 complete
941000107445 complete
941000107445 complete
941000107445 complete
941000107445 complete
941000107446 complete
941000107447 complete
941000107451 complete
941000107451 complete
941000107451 complete
941000107451 complete
941000107451 complete
941000107456 complete
941000107456 complete
941000107456 complete
941000107456  complete

Comment: thank you! the formula I have now counts them all giving a result of 18 - because some have duplicate ID's I would like a formula that returns a result of 6 thus eliminating multiple order locations 18 orders 6 locations

Comment: @Tom: I have updated the answer.