# Fetching Data entries from several sheets but ignoring duplicates (without losing count that is)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a detailed article count list, consisting of several sheets, each sheet representing a different category. Some articles however can exist in multiple categories.
How do I fetch the data entries of all those sheets, without keeping the duplicates that may exist?

As an example:

> I have Article A, B and C
>
> Then I have the sheets 'Box 1', 'Box 2', 'Box 3'
>
> In Box 1 I have Article A and B
>
> In Box 2 I have Article B and C
>
> In Box 3 I have Article A and C
>
> Visual Aid --> [image: one sheet]
>
> My goal is to make a summary that lists the entries of the boxes without duplicating the articles, like so
>
> [image: summary]

I would like this to be dynamic, so I can freely edit the "box sheets" individually without having to edit or copy into the summary all over again.

During search for answers on this topic I found this solution which eliminates one of the problems:
[How to compare two columns in Excel and delete duplicates](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/09/05/compare-two-columns-remove-duplicates/#two-columns-different-worksheets)

For counting without "keeping duplicates" I found this question, which I yet need to test if it works in my scenario:
[Count if two criteria match while ignoring duplicates](https://superuser.com/questions/390811/count-if-two-criteria-match-while-ignoring-duplicates)

My problem with this is keeping the count up-to-date with the worksheets.

Another forum post I found was this scenario of [counting across multiple worksheets](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/91630-count-number-of-occurrences-across-multiple-sheets-without-using-vba)

It goes even further though. 
What if I have similar Article names like A, B and C, but the articles are actually variants like -0, -1 or -2?

This would add another row to the summary and make the "dynamic" of it much harder to accomplish:

> **SAMPLE-Visual Aid! This isn't dynamic but created by hand in one sheet!**
>
> [image: sample end result]

This "little change" elevates the complication to a degree I can't really handle anymore, so I'm seeking help. 
I'm looking for a somewhat simple solution to this or at least an explanation of how such data could be processed/summerized dynamically.

**To summerize / tl;dr**

**I'm looking for a dynamic function, possibly consisting of multiple stitched together functions, which will do the following:**

1. Gather ALL data entries across multiple worksheets, keeping their variant row and count
2. Summing together the duplicates of all data entries and "eliminating those entries", but without losing their counts or variants.

*My progress on this so far was only that I consolidated the data from the multiple sheets and then edited the third row with the function:*

=INDEX(Articles!A:B;COMPARE($A2;Articles!A:A;);2)

*This function simply grabs the name of the article and compares it to an reference list of available articles, which results in losing individual variant counts.*

Comment: You have almost solved it as I can find the Summary on right lists `AABBC`. Now what you have to do is apply formula to extract `ABC` as Unique and in adjacent column apply `SUMIF` you get `A-- 4` and others.

Comment: Well not almost. The example I made was all in one sheet and without the dynamic I am hoping for. It was supposed to serve more as a visual aid and to reduce the screenshot amount I put it all in one sheet.

I would wish for my final result to be in a seperate sheet named Summary, containing the consolidated data from the sheets Box 1, Box 2 and Box 3. This consolidated however can't be made with the consolidate function, since that would eliminate any variants of A, B and C.