# Creating a constant count of unique values for one variable by another variable in MS Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out how to create a variable that gives me a count of the number of unique dates for each person in my dataset.

For example, if I have:

```
A  B    
K 9/12
K 9/12
K 9/13
K 9/14
J 9/12
J 9/14
J 9/15
J 9/16
F 9/14
F 9/14
F 9/15
```

I want Excel to return:

```
A  B   C
K 9/12 3
K 9/12 3
K 9/13 3
K 9/14 3
J 9/12 4
J 9/14 4
J 9/15 4
J 9/16 4
F 9/14 2
F 9/14 2
F 9/15 2
```

I tend to work more in Stata and R, but I'm trying to put together an excel workbook with formulas to help a coworker who does not normally work with data. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you just need a count for each unique person, you can use a Pivot Table.  If you select "add to data model", it will expose a `Distinct Count` value item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as an Array Formula (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$12=A2,MATCH($B$2:$B$12,$B$2:$B$12,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$12)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))
```

[image]

<sub>Big thanks to @barryhoudini for [writing this formula](https://superuser.com/a/390843/529100)</sub>